# group_by on database query result Not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, activerecord

So I have the following simple database table to make the matter simpler

```
Client_id | Client_name     | Client_state 

1         | John            | New York           
2         | Nick            | New York                     
3         | Marc            | California                  
4         | Jason           | California         
5         | Gabriel         | Seattle                    
6         | Alex            | Seattle
```

So whenever i click the following button

```
<button type="button" class="btn results btn-primary">results</button>
```

I have a Javascript function that makes an ajax call to get the results back. Here's my function

```
$('.results').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
                    type: 'ajax',
                    method: 'get',
                    async: false,
                    url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>client_results',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response)
                    }, //end success function
                    error: function(){
                        alert('Error');
                    }

                });//end ajax call
```

Here's my modal function for this

```
      public function client_results(){
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->group_by("Client_state"); // whenever i remove this i get all the rows without a problem 
            $query = $this->db->get('Clients');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
```

So the problem is whenever I try to group the rows by their state I get the following error!
but as soon as I remove the groupe by a line of code everything works perfectly and I get all the rows logged in the console without an issue! the problem is I want them to be grouped by state!

Please help me out!

Comment: What are you expecting to get back from that query? `SELECT *` doesn't really make sense when doing grouping.

Comment: You probably want [`ORDER BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html), not [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html). Order By sorts all of the rows in a specific order. Group by combines rows based on the column specified, which is great for counting the number of rows or adding up the total in another column.

Comment: Or `WHERE`, if you're trying to only get client with a specific `Client_state`

Comment: @TheGentleman i'm not trying to select a specific state , i don't need where ! i want the rows grouped , that's it !

Comment: @aynber so i need to order in order to group them?

Comment: @TheGentleman i'm expecting to get the queries grouped by their state in arrays or something similar !

Comment: Correct. It sounds like you want to sort them so that you still have 6 lines in State order, so that's a sort. If you want a multi-dimensional array, like `['California' => ['Marc', 'Jason'], 'New York' => ['John', 'Nick']...`, then you'll have to build that out yourself since MySQL just returns simple rows/arrays.

Comment: @aynber exactly ! so there's no way to do that with built int mysql functions ? if the so , what's the role of group_by then?

Comment: Group By is for creating aggregates. Like `SELECT Client_state, COUNT(id) as total from Clients`, which will return something like `California 2|New York 2`, or `SELECT order_id, count(id) as num_items, SUM(item_total) as subtotal from order_items GROUP BY order_id` to get a count and/or total of columns.

Comment: @aynber thank you mate :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL cannot do this natively. You'll have to get what you need and then iterate over the loop using a programming language (probably PHP in this case). Here is a simplistic version of what that algorithm would look like.

```
public function client_results(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $query = $this->db->get('Clients');
    $results = $query->result_array();
    $groupedResults = array();

    foreach($results as $row) {
        if (!array_key_exists($row->Client_state, $groupedResults)) {
            $groupedResults[$row->Client_state] = array();
        }
        $groupedResults[$row->Client_state][] = $row->Client_name;
    }

    return $groupedResults;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `group by` doesn't make much sense when doing a `select *`. Not on Codeigniter's Query Builder, not on SQL

The reason is that grouping is intended to produce a grouped summary of all data (rows get merged), but you're not being specific regarding what do you want to do with the grouped rows.

For instance, take your sample data. If you group by State, what will happen with the `client_id` and `client_name` columns? SQL doesn't really know what to do with them because your query is ambiguous.

Do you want to get how many clients you have on each state?
Try

```
$this->db->select('Client_state,count(*) as n');
$this->db->from('Clients');
$this->db->group_by('Client_state');
```

The above will output:

```
Client_state | n

New York     | 2
California   | 2
Seattle      | 2
```

do you want to add client IDs of all clients on each state?
Try

```
$this->db->select('Client_state,sum(Client_id) as sum');
$this->db->from('Clients');
$this->db->group_by('Client_state');
```

the above will output:

```
Client_state | sum

New York     | 3
California   | 7
Seattle      | 11
```

Remember, when grouping you need to be specific both regarding what do you want to group by and what your desired result is.